# Use of unbase64 in httpd 2.4

Tags: base64, httpd.conf

I need to set a variable in http header after authentication in httpd.conf. But the value is base 64 encoded. I need to decode it before setting it in the header for which I am trying to use unbase64 of apache httpd.

I have tried like below. But nothing helps.

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=NEW_VAL:%{unbase64:%{AUTHORIZE_VAL}}]
Header set user.sid "%{NEW_VAL}e"
```

Can please help me in understanding the usage of this or is there any way to decode the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps someone. I have written a script for base 64 decoding and configured  RewriteMap for that script. Then used that map for conversion in RewriteRule.

Reference : [this](https://polyglotmuse.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/apache-httpd-magic-with-rewritemap/)